# how to submit same form after open on different button click in PHP?

Tags: php, form-submit

I have single form modal. when clicking on 'Request for Demo' button form will be open and this is submit for only one div. i need to submit same form for multiple div.

Following is html code for div click button and after clicking on "Request for Demo" button form will be open

currently when clicking on "request for demo" button form is open and saving in database but i want to save same form when clicking on multiple div "request for demo" button.

Comment: You should escape the user data! This is a risky implementation.

Comment: i need to do it

Comment: But I do not get clear what you want to do. First step is to click "request for demo", second step is to send the form. But what is your expected outcome?

Comment: there is "request for demo" button in each div after clicking on this button form will open and  i need to save this form in database

Comment: form is common and i want to open it separately after clicking on each div button and submit separately

Comment: In this case you can reuse the form. Open it with a click, submit it and open it again.

Comment: but how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this here: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

```
$( ".demo-btn" ).on( "click", function() {
  dialog.dialog( "open" );
});
```

And change the id attribute for the buttons. Since an ID has to be unique use a class instead. The snippet above shows how to open the dialog on each item of class demo-btn.

Comment: dialog is open after clicking on button but i want to save same dialog after clicking on each div button